# No sound on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

So I recently dual-booted my pc with windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, but I am having trouble with the sound in Ubuntu.

When I check out my sound output in `pulseaudio` I can see that my pc is detecting sound and trying to channel it out through my headphones, but there is no sound. Btw this is working perfectly fine in windows.

[image: pavucontrol screenshot]

I also tried `pacmd`:

[image: pacmd output (part 1)]
[image: pacmd output (part 2)]

`sudo alsa force-reload` and `sudo init 6` did not work either.

Comment: Are all output devices showing under 'Sound'?

Comment: Can you try the following command in the terminal? Usually it works immediately but try restarting as well. sudo alsactl restore If permissions are denied, try using sudo. From : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2323498 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1583801

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this commands worked for me.
Socket is enabled by default:

```
$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio.socket
```

If you want `pulseaudio` to start right after login:

```
$ systemctl --user enable pulseaudio
```

[ArchLinux source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=206679)

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove and install again drivers.

```
sudo apt-get remove alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

and force again alsa loading:

```
sudo alsa force-reload﻿
```

It wasn't enough for me, so I'd to remove the directory for creating a new one.

```
 mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse
```

Reboot for creating the new files automatically, and it should work.