# No more sound in Ubuntu 18.04 HP Envy

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hp

this is the first time I am posting here but I am kind of desperate.

I don't have any more sound on my laptop, only "Dummy output" whereas it was working fine yesterday. I tried several methods, uninstalling and reinstalling *alsa* and *pulseaudio* then force reload, stop win10 from hibernating, literally everything I could find on the internet.
Here are some unsuccessful solutions I tried :

- [No sound on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081748/no-sound-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Dummy output, no sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099053/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-dummy-output-no-sound)
- https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html
- [No sound in Ubuntu 18.04 HP notebook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042318/no-sound-in-ubuntu-18-04-hp-notebook)

I have a dual boot Win10/Ubuntu 18.04. Here are some information that could be useful for you :

```
wob@hp-envy:~$ inxi -SMA
System:    Host: hp-envy Kernel: 5.3.0-42-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: HP product: HP ENVY Laptop 13-aq0xxx v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: N/A
           Mobo: HP model: 85E2 v: 29.27 serial: N/A
           UEFI: Insyde v: F.08 date: 08/15/2019
Audio:     Card Intel Device 9dc8 driver: snd_soc_skl
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.3.0-42-generic
wob@hp-envy:~$ inxi -SMA | cs
wob@hp-envy:~$ alsamixer 
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
alexis@hp-envy:~$ pulseaudio 
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

If you have any idea of a process to find more information about what is wrong and/or how I could fix this, please help me.
Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, now this is probably related with https://askubuntu.com/questions/1218041/ubuntu-18-04-audio-disappeared-after-update solved

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

Add the following line to the end of this file:

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

Save and close the file and reboot your system. You should have the audio back.

Reboot

Regards

Comment: Thanks for yout answer, unfortunately it didn't work for me. I still haven't found a solution, I am sadly considering reinstalling ubuntu.

Regards

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I have tried a lot of things and have some conclusions now but can't make it work.

Comment: Unfortunateley not, I will reinstall.

Comment: Oh man, you saved me, I tried many things nothing worked but this answer did worked.