# Ubuntu 18.04.4: audio suspended/idle not working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

**Question**

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4. There is no sound.

As suggested [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sound-nosound.html.en), audio device information obtained using  `sudo lspci -v` is as follows:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 146
    Memory at d1228000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at d1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

**Tested methods**

Following are the questions that I have looked into.

[Q1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081748/no-sound-on-ubuntu-18-04) Following is the output of systemctl command

```
$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio.socket
pulseaudio.socket - Sound 
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
Listen: /run/user/1000/pulse/native (Stream)
```

After this, as suggested I used the command `systemctl --user enable pulseaudio`.

---

[Q2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038490/how-do-you-set-a-default-audio-output-device-in-ubuntu-18-04) As suggested here, I checked `pactl list short sinks`. Following is the outcome. It shows the device is suspended.

```
pactl list short sinks
0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

Then, I used `pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo`. The suspended status did not change. Hence, I searched for another solution.

---

[Q3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445386/pulseaudio-server-connection-failure-connection-refused-debian-stretch) As suggested here, I reinstalled pulseaudio and alsa-base. Following is output:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
libwebrtc-audio-processing1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
alsa-base* pulseaudio*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 2 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 4,588 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 426510 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
Removing pulseaudio (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
(Reading database ... 426290 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for pulseaudio (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7) ...
Purging configuration files for alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
(base) neeraj@neeraj-personal:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'alsa-base' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pulseaudio' is not installed, so not removed
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libwebrtc-audio-processing1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

---

```
(base) neeraj@neeraj-personal:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libwebrtc-audio-processing1
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 691 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 426279 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libwebrtc-audio-processing1:amd64 (0.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

---

```
(base) neeraj@neeraj-personal:~$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libwebrtc-audio-processing1
Suggested packages:
  apmd alsa-oss oss-compat pavumeter paman paprefs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  alsa-base libwebrtc-audio-processing1 pulseaudio
0 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1,193 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,279 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 alsa-base all 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 [145 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libwebrtc-audio-processing1 amd64 0.3-1 [260 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 pulseaudio amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7 [788 kB]
Fetched 1,193 kB in 4s (307 kB/s)   
Selecting previously unselected package alsa-base.
(Reading database ... 426276 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../alsa-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb ...
Unpacking alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libwebrtc-audio-processing1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libwebrtc-audio-processing1_0.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwebrtc-audio-processing1:amd64 (0.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio.
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio_1%3a11.1-1ubuntu7.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7) ...
Setting up alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libwebrtc-audio-processing1:amd64 (0.3-1) ...
Setting up pulseaudio (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.7) ...
Adding user pulse to group audio
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
(base) neeraj@neeraj-personal:~$ sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get -y autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo sync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3
```

After takin these steps following is the outcome of the pactl:

```
(base) neeraj@neeraj-personal:~$ pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   IDLE
```

---

Checked for additional drivers as suggested in an answer. Following is the screenshot.

[image: additional drivers]

No drivers are listed there.

---

Attempted to connect using a Bluetooth headset. Headset paired with the laptop but did not connect and hence did not show up in the device list.

---

Now, after restarting the laptop, following is the situation. But there is no sound.

```
pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
```

Another restart and it shows suspended again

```
pactl list short sinks
1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   SUSPENDED
```

How to proceed to start the sound?

I updated the system from 18.04 to 19.04 and the sound issue resolved. I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1

just go to update app and then go to additional drives then choose the latest version of GPU it will work fine

don't forget to use

```
sudo apt-get udpate
```

Comment: I do not have drivers in the additional software. Shared in the question.
What changes should I make, so that I would have drivers in this particular section?

Comment: no way you should find it in the additional drivers if you not find it just restart the system

Comment: Restarted the system as suggested. No additional drivers yet.

Comment: change the country for source updating choose the best server option and pick what it gave it to you then after that update the system with sudo apt-get update and see what will happen

Comment: Chose the best server option and picked what it gave me. No sound yet.